# Styling custom user control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to create a custom control which contains a few shapes, rectangle, ellipse and label. However the construction of this feels like a bit of a hack. My questions....

1. Is there a way to layout the contents of this so its more dynamic
2. Make the ellipse shape always stay vertically centered
3. Set a max width for the rectangle
4. The height of the rectangle will grow to fit the contents of the text

   - If 4 is not possible, can i at least make the long titles of text appear as **Node A has a l...**?

Currently I'm hacking it together using funky margins and whatnot to place things in the correct place. Hope you can help. Thanks guys.

[image]

Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.VNode"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200">

    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Backplate" Width="70" Height="24" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" Opacity="0.75"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                    <GradientStop Color="#db4a38" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#cf4635" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Ellipse Width="18" Height="18" Margin="68,41,114,41" Fill="sc#1,.02,.02,.02">

        </Ellipse>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Text="Label" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Foreground="White" Margin="91,42,-91,-42" FontSize="11">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="2" Direction="-45"/>
            </TextBlock.Effect>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `Border` control instead of `Rectangle`as `Rectangle` control does not have `Content` property.

```
        <Grid>
            <Border CornerRadius="5" MaxWidth="200">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" Opacity="0.75"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                        <GradientStop Color="#db4a38" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#cf4635" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Width="18" Height="18" Fill="sc#1,.02,.02,.02">
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" MaxWidth="50" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap">Node A has a long title</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>            
        </Grid>
```

Comment: perfect, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#db4a38" MaxWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DockPanel Margin="5">
        <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Black" Height="18" Width="18" />
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="Node A has a long title" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```